# pass variable between two .html pages

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I basically have a search box, I am trying to get the value inserted and use on a separate `/results.htm` screen via the submit button. I've been able to get and process the results within the same page; but I am trying to do this after redirecting to a new page

**/search.html**

```
 <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery("#submit").click(function() {
            var ZipSearch = jQuery("#Zipcode").val();
        });
    });
    </script>
    <div class="search_bar">
        <form action=""><input type="text" name="Zipcode" id="Zipcode" value="" maxlength="5" placeholder="Zipcode">
        <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/></form>
    </div>
```

Want to keep input value content from /search.htm within a variable on next page, separate, **/results.htm**

How can I keep the user input value and use on my separate 'results' page?

Comment: You want to use the jquery value `ZipSearch` how about localstorage?

Comment: Add an input via jquery, or do the form submission via jquery.

Comment: What are you going to search for this ZipCode? A database??

Comment: Do you mean you want to keep `search.html` _and_ `results.html` opened at the same time and passing the search button value between both windows without passing by your server ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove all the JavaScript from *search.htm*. There's no point in writing custom software to do things HTML has built-in.

Set the `action` of the form to the URL of the second page (`action="/results.htm"`).

Change the button to a submit button (`type="submit"`)

Read the data from the query string (`location.search` in JavaScript or `$_GET` in PHP).

Comment: I think you should clarify WHY this is the correct course of action, not just walk them through how to do it. The OP can't learn if you just hold their hand the entire time

Comment: This answer should not be overlooked. Using standard web form submission is a basic thing most 'modern' developers don't understand. They should learn this before they move into AJAX calls. They would better understand the basics and know hoe the web really works.